# Migrated to MSE, did not get enough attention. What to do?

Tags: discussion

[This question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051220/chern-class-cohomology-coefficients-complex-real-integral) is migrated to MSE from MO.

It did not get enough attention in MSE even after offering bounty.

[Another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3053609/chern-class-of-a-principal-g-bundle-for-a-compact-lie-group-g) with a bounty with not even a single comment.

I think topics like Characteristic classes get very less attention/not suitable there. Out of $395$ questions, $134$ are unanswered. Most of them does not even have a comment. In November four questions have that tag, two of which has no answers. In October four questions have that tag, none of them has answers. This is more or less the situation.

What to do in this case?

Should MO users allow to some extent not so high level questions with that tag to survive here?

Comment: I will just add that the stats can be found [in the list of top users](https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/characteristic-classes/topusers) - for (characteristic-classes) they say at the moment: 100% unanswered/7 days, 66.7% unanswered/30 days, 33.9% unanswered/all time. Some statistics related to tags which do not get enough attention: [Best and worst tags for % answered rate](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/23148).

Comment: Thanks for your information

Comment: If you can answer other questions with the tag, do so. And ask good questions about the subject; maybe an expert will get interested. You might also consider asking a similar question at their meta site.